# Python Синхронизация JSON данных

Tags: python, база-данных, json, multiprocessing, синхронизация

Есть программа, в которой запущен процесс. В этом процессе циклично запускаются уже другие процессы. Мне нужно синхронизировать данные между ВСЕМИ процессами, как родительстким, так и дочерними.

В данный момент данные одного процесса перезаписывают данные другого, из-за чего часть данных теряется.

1. Я пробовал использовать multiprocessing.Queue, однако это позволяет связать лишь два процесса.
2. Я пытался передавать экземпляр класса в args процесса, чтобы попытаться синхронизировать данные с помощью него, используя self, однако данные изменялись лишь в области дочернего процесса -- в родительском процессе этих изменений не было.
3. Я пытался использовать глобальную переменную, но, опять же, даже при указании в функции global varname, значение переменной varname процессом не изменялось.
4. Я пытался реализовать идею с помощью multiprocessing.Manager, но почему-то он не изменяет значение в manager следующим кодом:

   ```
   from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

   def f(manager):
       manager["users"][0]["coins"]+=1

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       manager = Manager().dict()
       manager.update({"users": [{"id": 1, "coins": 0}]})
       p = Process(target = f, args = [manager, ])
       p.start()
       p.join()
       print(manager)
   ```

Возможно ли как-то передать в multiprocessing.Process переменные среды, чтобы реализовать синхронизацию с помощью второго варианта? Если нет, то какой вариант будет наиболее оптимальным для решения задачи?

Comment: А `multiprocessing.Pool` не подходит для вашей задачи? Средства надо подбирать под конкретную задачу, а вы начали сразу со средств. Невозможно подсказать правильные средства для решения задачи, параметры которой неизвестны. Может у неё узкое место не там где вы ищете решение.

Answer (score 2):

Типы должны быть из `Manager`, иначе не будет синхронизации данных после выполнения кода в отдельном процессе.

Поменял словарь и список на тот, что из `Manager`:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager


def f(users_data):
    users_data["users"][0]["coins"] += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    users_data = manager.dict()
    user_data = manager.dict({"id": 1, "coins": 0})
    users_data["users"] = manager.list([user_data])

    p = Process(target=f, args=[users_data])
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print(users_data['users'][0])
    # {'id': 1, 'coins': 1}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Ещё вопрос, если не сложно. Есть код: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/bT5B7QZnT7/   Почему в функции global_handler условие if self.queue содержит [], так как при вызове извне выводится целый список?

Comment: `self.ids_sum = 0` это обычный тип и он не будет синхронизирован при выполнении кода в другом процессе

Comment: А какие типы являются "необычными"?

Comment: Все типы, что есть в питоне и не входят в типы-прокси из `multiprocessing`. Кст, добавил `print` в `message_handler` и ничего... тут или нет выполнения функции или она выполняется, но почему то из процесса, в которая она выполняется, нет об этом сообщений... хз, в общем, я особо не работал с этим модулем, нужно гуглить :)